# Checking for numbers only in EdditText boxes

Tags: android

I am making a program where you enter two numbers into two different editText boxes and it will use those numbers to make a range. I want the Custom button, when it says "ready," to only work when theres a number in each box. But right now the program gives me an error if I click the Custom button with nothing in the edditText boxes. But when I do put numbers in the edditText boxes the program works. Any help?

EDIT: How can I check if there are values in the EditText boxes?

```
    Custom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            CBox1.setEnabled(true);
            CBox2.setEnabled(true);
            Custom.setText("Ready");
            Max.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Min.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            Custom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    int b1 = Integer.parseInt(CBox1.getText().toString());
                    int b2 = Integer.parseInt(CBox2.getText().toString());

                    if ((b1 > 0) && (b2 > 0)) {

                        Intent goToCustomMode = new Intent(AdditionDifficulty.this, AdditionHard.class);
                        startActivity(goToCustomMode);

                        System.out.println("MY TEXT IS HERE " + Integer.parseInt(CBox1.getText().toString()));
                        System.out.println("MY TEXT IS HERE " + Integer.parseInt(CBox2.getText().toString()));

                    }else{

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: what i understand is there should be number in editext and should be greater than zero then make the button clickable and go to second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the error you are getting includes

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

You can either check the input before trying to use:-

`int b1 = Integer.parseInt(CBox1.getText().toString());`

e.g.

One solution could be to check that something has been input using :-

```
   if (CBox1.getText().toString().length() > 0 && 
            CBox2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        b1 = Integer.parseInt(CBox1.getText().toString());
        b2 = Integer.parseInt(CBox2.getText().toString());

        // do your stuff here
    } else {
        // handle no input here e.g.
        CBox1.requestFocus();
    }
```

Another solution could be to trap the error(s) using something like :-

```
    try {
        b1 = Integer.parseInt(CBox1.getText().toString());
        b2 = Integer.parseInt(CBox2.getText().toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // handle error here e.g.
        CBox1.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    // do your stuff here
```

A third solution would be to hide the button until there was valid data e.g.

```
    CBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CBox1);
    CBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CBox2);
    doGoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doGoButton);

    doGoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    CBox1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (CBox1.getText().toString().length() > 0
                    &&
                    CBox2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                doGoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                doGoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    CBox2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (CBox1.getText().toString().length() > 0
                    &&
                    CBox2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                doGoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                doGoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

> Note the solutions do not check invalid data e.g. A being input (it is
>   assumed that the input type has been set via the layout e.g. by using
>   `android:inputType="number"`)

---

### Solution one as applied to your code would be:-

```
Custom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        CBox1.setEnabled(true);
        CBox2.setEnabled(true);
        Custom.setText("Ready");
        Max.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Min.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (CBox1.getText().toString().length() > 0 && 
            CBox2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            b1 = Integer.parseInt(CBox1.getText().toString());
            b2 = Integer.parseInt(CBox2.getText().toString());

            if ((b1 > 0) && (b2 > 0)) {
                System.out.println("MY TEXT IS HERE " + Integer.parseInt(CBox1.getText().toString()));
                System.out.println("MY TEXT IS HERE " + Integer.parseInt(CBox2.getText().toString()));

                Intent goToCustomMode = new Intent(AdditionDifficulty.this, AdditionHard.class);
                startActivity(goToCustomMode);

         } else {
             System.out.println("MY TEXT WAS INVALID");
             // handle no input here e.g.
             CBox1.requestFocus();
         }
     }
 });
```

> Note! `CBox1.requestFocus` places the focus (i.e. moves the cursor) to
>   the first input. You'd probably want to check which input is incorrect
>   and if CBox2 is incorrect use `CBox2.requestFocus();`. You may want to
>   add a `system.out.println` to indicate invalid input.

---

### Solution two as applied to your code would be:-

```
Custom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        CBox1.setEnabled(true);
        CBox2.setEnabled(true);
        Custom.setText("Ready");
        Max.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Min.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        try {
            b1 = Integer.parseInt(CBox1.getText().toString());
            b2 = Integer.parseInt(CBox2.getText().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MY TEXT WAS INVALID");
            CBox1.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        // Only invoke AdditionHard activity if input integeres are greater than 0
        if ((b1 > 0) && (b2 > 0)) {

            Intent goToCustomMode = new Intent(AdditionDifficulty.this, AdditionHard.class);
            startActivity(goToCustomMode);

            System.out.println("MY TEXT IS HERE " + Integer.parseInt(CBox1.getText().toString()));
            System.out.println("MY TEXT IS HERE " + Integer.parseInt(CBox2.getText().toString()));
        } else {
            System.out.println("MY TEXT HAS A 0 so returning doing nothing!");
        }
     }
 });
```

---

### Solution three as applied to your code would be:-

Note! this is before (or could be after) setting the `onClickListener` NOT IN IT. It's adding listeners for the `EditTexts` and basically does a check when the text is changed e.g. something is typed in or removed. It then only makes the button visible when text is present in both.

```
        Custom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        CBox1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (CBox1.getText().toString().length() > 0
                        &&
                        CBox2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    Custom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    Custom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        CBox2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (CBox1.getText().toString().length() > 0
                        &&
                        CBox2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    Custom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    Custom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Then your existing code

```
    Custom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            CBox1.setEnabled(true);
            CBox2.setEnabled(true);
            Custom.setText("Ready");
            Max.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Min.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ...........etc.....
```

---

### Passing values to invoked activity

*Are you expecting to get the values **b1** and **b2** in the invoked activity, if so you should place the values into the Intent e.g. before `startActivity(goToCustomMode);`?*

```
    Intent goToCustomMode = new Intent(AdditionDifficulty.this, AdditionHard.class);
    intent.putExtra("B1VALUE",b1);
    intent.putExtra("B2VALUE",b2);
    startActivity(goToCustomMode);
```

You then use the following in the invoked activity to retrieve the values:-

```
    int passedb1 = getIntent().getIntExtra("B1VALUE",0);
    int passedb2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("B2VALUE",0);
```

> Note! the key e.g. **B1VALUE** MUST MATCH the key used when putting
>   the **`intentExtra`** it's what identifies the value. Additionally
>   **`getIntExtra`** requires a default value to be returned if no match is
>   found, so here I've used 0. You would then have to check that the
>   values retrieved are not 0 (i.e. the respective **`intentExtra`** was not found).

Comment: Thanks MikeT for the help, but I entered the three different codes and none of them worked for me. Maybe it was the way I entered the code. Any more help would be great.

Comment: @JamesD I assumed that you'd know where to and how to adopt the code. As such I've updated the answer by including the first given solution (not checked though). I may, time permitting, update the answer for how the second (although this is basically a replacement for the first solution) and the third (this needs to be coded in the `onCreate` method, which I didn't make clear) solutions.

Comment: @JamesD, good suggest you try 2nd and then 3rd (note 3rd can be used with 1st or 2nd). 2nd is better of 1 and 2 as it will also trap non-numerics. Just doing 3rd now.

Comment: @JamesD OK all three done now. Would appreciate you ticking the answer and up-voting if you found this helpful. Of course if you have issue with 2nd and 3rd options just let me know. Using `@MikeT` will notify me.